# i have inserted data in databse but not knowing how to show in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting this error
Missing required parameters for [Route: service.show] [URI: service/{service}].

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $service = Service::find($id);
        return view('service.show')->withPost($service);
        //
    }
```

controller

i have one blade file to show.

Route file .

```
Route::resource('service', 'ServiceController');
Route::get('service/{id}', 'ServiceController@show');
```

Is this route correct

Comment: Which of these lines causes that error message? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: same error message i used all of them

Comment: i just now saw the debug in my system it shows Query
Query
insert into
  `services` (
    `service_type`,
    `service_name`,
    `service_price`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
  )
values
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Time
40.69
Connection name
mysql
0
Brillare
1
deep root
2
600
3
2019-09-11 07:43:01
4
2019-09-11 07:43:01
Query
Query
select
  *
from
  `users`
where
  `id` = ?
limit
  1
Time
1.1
Connection name
mysql
0
4 i think it is taking from some other table

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug this problem? How could that `INSERT` query interfer with the given code? There is nothing triggering a new database row in that code

Comment: I am having 2 files name show.blade.php one in view/post folder one in view folder should i change this file name show.blade.php is it ok or i should change the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

It is easier when you read [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) Documentation.

This are some teachers of Laravel [Coders Tape](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQI-Ym2rLZx52vEoqlPQMdg) and [Brad Traversy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA). You can learn from them from scratch

You can do it this way.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $service = Service::find($id);
        return view('service.show', compact('service'));
        //
    }
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::resource('/service', 'ServicesController');
```

**BLADE / VIEW**

```
<div>
 {{$service->id}}
</div>
```

Comment: same error i am getting and In table i have stored id as service_id

Comment: try to use this in **blade** `{{$service->service_id}}`

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: service.show] [URI: service/{service}]. i get this error

Comment: I am having 2 files name show.blade.php  one in view/post folder one in view folder should i change this file name show.blade.php

Comment: are you sure you are using show? the request for show should look like this if you have data in the database it will redirect `http:\\localhost:8000/services/1`

Comment: yep i am using show.blade .php i have data in table also not getting how to put in route and should i change show.blade.php name

Comment: try to `dd(service)` in your controller after you `service = Service::findOrFail($id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $service = Service::find($id);
    return view('service.show')->with('service', $service);
}
```

In your blade,

```
<div>
     {{ $service}}
</div>
```

Just use 2 curly braces `{{ }}` and put it inside the variable you use. In this example i used `service`

Comment: Can you explain which parts of your code solve the given error message?

Comment: I'm not in charge of accepting it, but if you want your answer to be accepted, you should add some explanation to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the show route with service id in parameter.

```
Route::get('service/{id}', 'ServiceController@show')->name('service.show');
<a href="{{ route('service.show', $id)">Show<a/>
```

If you wanna redirect to that route:

```
return \Redirect::route('service.show', $id);
```

Comment: Route::get('service/{id}', this id or in mytable i have given service_id that one

Comment: I am having 2 files name show.blade.php one in view/post folder one in view folder should i change this file name show.blade.php

Comment: I would be good to have blade file names matching the method names, however it is up to you. If this file is in post folder it will be ```return view('post.show')```

Answer (score 0):

**Route**
I would give the route a unique name, so you can easily generate links.

```php
Route::name('service_info')->get('/service/{id}', 'ServiceController@show');
```

**Controller**
I think you need to use $request.
I added a check for 404 issues, but you could also check that in a middleware.

```php
public function show(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $service = Service::find($request->id);

    if ($service === null) {
        abort(404, "service not found");
    }

    return view('show', [
        'service' => $service
    ]);
}
```

**Blade**
And in the blade you can use the service with {{}}

```html
<div>
    {{$service}}
</div>
```

Or if 'Service' has attributes like 'name' or 'id' and you want to use them:

```html
<div>
    {{$service->id}}: {{$service->name}}
    {{$service->id.': '.$service->name}}
</div>
```

Both are possible.

Comment: If you use the route function it should look like this:  ```route('service_info', ['id' => 1])```  And the URI should look like: ```localhost/service/1```  
If you still get the error, please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I am having 2 files name show.blade.php one in view/post folder one in view folder should i change this file name show.blade.php

Comment: All your views should be in ```resources/views/``` or in subfolders of that path. All your views should be .blade.php files.

Comment: yes it is in right path in views i created one folder post which has one show.blade.php and in views i have show.blade.php which i am using now should i change the name or it will work like that only

Comment: So you use ```resources/views/show.blade.php```. Then return the view like that:
```return view('show', [
        'service' => $service
]);```